# Deleting feature dataset containing network dataset from ArcSDE database?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, delete, network-dataset

I have trouble with deleting unwanted feature datasets from ArcSDE.

Datasets contain network datasets which cannot be deleted either and I think they cause the problem. Options to delete or remove are simply greyed out. I haven't found anything useful in the web so far about this, any suggestions?

[image: options are grayed out]

Comment: do you have the db privileges to delete?

Comment: Only the owner can delete a feature dataset.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm the owner, I have all privilages for this databese and I created this dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: you need to have network analyst license enabled to be able to delete network datasets. I created those datasets some time ago, leter disabled network analyst license and that coused the problem. This is not so obvious that you need to have this license just to remove data from your database.